# How do i flip a list of lists?

Tags: python

How do i flip `e2` so it becomes `e4`?

input

```
e2 = [
 [255,191,127],
 [191,127, 63],
 [127, 63, 0]]
```

output

```
e4 = [
 [127, 63, 0],
 [191,127, 63],
 [255,191,127]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task is basically inverting a list

```
e4 = e2[::-1]
```

reverting also the elements would be

```
e4 = [el[::-1] for el in e2[::-1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to reverse the list. You can use list slicing for this, like so:

```
e4 = e2[::-1]
print(e4)
```

#### Output

---

```
[[127, 63, 0],
 [191,127, 63],
 [255,191,127]]
```

Here, `[::-1]` means that you are slicing from the start of the list to the end of the list. The `-1` tells Python to slice the list backwards, i.e., reverse it.

Answer (score 0):

```
   e2 = [
     [255,191,127],
     [191,127, 63],
     [127, 63, 0]]
    
    e2.reverse()
    e4 = e2
    for i in e4:
     print(i)
```

Comment: Note: `reverse` is a void. You will need to first call it then assign.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is call `list.reverse`:

```py
e2.reverse()
e4 = e2
```